# How to write a Test class for an if statement

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

How do i write a test class for following:

```
if(totalAmount != 0)
{                   
  //Find Inkoop_Uren__c record having maximun Betaald_max__c  
  Partij__c partijMaxBetaaldValue = dossierRecord.Partijen__r[0];
  for(Partij__c partijRecord : dossierRecord.Partijen__r)
  {                                          
   if(partijRecord.Betaald_max__c != null &&   partijMaxBetaaldValue.Betaald_max__c !=null
       && partijRecord.Betaald_max__c >= partijMaxBetaaldValue.Betaald_max__c)
    {                              
          partijMaxBetaaldValue.Betaald_max__c = partijRecord.Betaald_max__c;
    }                                           
  }
}
```

Comment: you need to make sure that totalAmount is greater than zero, create test data accordingly and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Im stuck with Totaal_Reisuren_Merlijn_new__c, which is arollup summary field`  Declaratie__c DeclaratieRecord = new Declaratie__c();
            DeclaratieRecord.Dossier__c =  dossierList[counter].Id;
            DeclaratieRecord.Totaal_Merlijn__c = Totaal_Reisuren_Merlijn_new__c + Totaal_Reiskosten_Melijn_new__c + Totaal_Uren_Merlijn__c;
            DeclaratieList.add(DeclaratieRecord);
        }
        insert DeclaratieList;`

Comment: @user42169 Update your question with test class you tried so far and code which populate `totalAmount` value.

Comment: @user42169 Please update your question with exact details about where you have stuck ! what code you have written for test class so far ! where you are encountering issue so that we can help you better, the more and appropriate details you will add here sooner  it will help you to get better answer.

Comment: post your test class of what you have tried so far

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to get it working the field Totaal_Reisuren_Merlijn_new__c was missing in my testclass